# What are the verses relating to meditation in the Tripitaka? And to what type of meditation does it relate to?

Tags: pali-canon, meditation-classification

Works like Visuddhimagga covers 40 types of meditations. I am looking for the original source of these meditations within the Tripitaka. Ideally with complete bibliographical references to the occurrences within the Tripitaka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The excerpt given below provides some references but in the pages following this one, the meditation subjects are explained and many more references are given. With this in mind, I suggest going to the link provided at the end of the excerpt and read these pages to extract the additional references.

> **§75 FORTY CONCENTRATION EXERCISES**
>
> There are forty concentration exercises (kammatthana) leading to the tranquility of the
> absorptions. They are:
>
> **I. Ten kasina exercises**: (1) earth kasina, (2) water kasina, (3) fire
> kasina, (4) wind kasina, (5) blue kasina, (6) yellow kasina, (7) red
> kasina, (8) white kasina, (9) light kasina, (10) space kasina. The
> older suttas replace the light kasina with the consciousness kasina,
> as at [AN 10:29](http://suttacentral.net/an10.29).
>
> **II. Ten perceptions of loathsomeness (asubha-sañña)**: a swollen-up
> corpse, a bluish discoloured corpse, a festering corpse, a split
> corpse, a gnawed corpse, a scattered corpse, a dismembered and
> scattered corpse, a blood-stained corpse, a corpse full of worms, a
> skeleton. More or less identical with these exercises are the nine
> cemetery contemplations in [MN 10](http://suttacentral.net/mn10) and [DN 22](http://suttacentral.net/dn22), and the contemplation in
> [AN 4:14](http://suttacentral.net/an4.14), quoted below.
>
> **III. Ten contemplations (anussati)**: (1) on the Buddha, (2) the
> Doctrine, (3) the Community of Noble Disciples, (4) morality, (5)
> liberality, (6) heavenly beings, (7) death, (8) body, (9)
> in-and-out-breathing, (10) peace. While 1-6 are mostly explained in
> one and the same sutta, (7)—(10) are described each separately in
> different suttas, e.g. (7) in [AN 8:73f](http://suttacentral.net/an8.73). (8) in [MN 119](http://suttacentral.net/mn119) (but not as in
> [MN 10](http://suttacentral.net/mn10), while in Vism the meditation refers to the thirty-two parts of
> the body); (9) in [MN 118](http://suttacentral.net/mn118); (10) in [AN 9:52](http://suttacentral.net/an9.52)-[61](http://suttacentral.net/an9.61), [10:26](http://suttacentral.net/an10.26).
>
> **IV. Four divine abodes (brahma-vihara)**: (1) all-em bracing kindness
> (metta), (2) compassion (karuna), (3) altruistic joy (mudita)), (4)
> equanimity (upekkha).
>
> **V. Four immaterial spheres (arupayatana)**: (1) sphere of boundless
> space, (2) sphere of boundless consciousness, (3) sphere of
> nothingness, (4) sphere of neither-perception-nor-non-perception.
>
> **VI. Perception of the loathsomeness of food.**
>
> **VII. Analysis of the four elements.**
>
> Neighbourhood concentration may be reached by **III** 1-7, 10; **VI**; and
> **VII**.
> The first jhana may be reached by **II** 1-10 and **III** 8.
> The first three jhanas may be reached by **IV** 1-3.
> The four jhanas may be reached by **I** 1-10 and **III** 9.
> The fourth jhana may be reached by **IV** 4.
> The immaterial attainments may be reached by **V** 1-4.
> The acquired image (uggaha-nimitta) and counter-image
> (patibhaga-nimitta) will arise only on realizing **I** 1-10; **II** 1-10; **III**
> 8, 9: hence in twenty-two exercises.
>
> For a full explanation of these forty exercises, see Vism III—XI.
> For further details about jhana, etc., see Fund. **IV**.
>
> *-[The Buddha's Path of Deliverance, p.75](http://www.shanyoma.org/yoma/The-Buddhas-Path-to-Deliverance.pdf#page=89) by Nyanatiloka Thera*

Comment: Great answer but could be a bit more bibliographic. The [Vinaya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinaya_Pitaka) also has Anapana and perhaps the [Abhidhamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhidhamma_Pitaka) also may have some references.

Comment: I up voted your answer. If I do not get a better answer in some time will accept it.

Comment: If you were intent on getting more comprehensive answers then I suggest editing the question but bear in mind that being exhaustive with the references is quite difficult & time-consuming some times.

Comment: I made some edits. See if this is sufficient.

Comment: Your answer does cover many of the references so is pretty good as it is.

Comment: I think it's sufficient. This way people intending to answer will know exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I would only add MN118 and MN119.  I wish I had this answer years ago!